# How to get current date in pega, YY-mm-dd format

Tags: pega

I want to get current system date in pega (Year-Month-Date)

> YYYY-mm-dd

format.

Answer (score 2):

Using

> @(Pega-RULES:DateTime).getCurrentDateStamp()

can get current system date in YYYY-mm-dd(Year-Month-Date) format.

Answer (score 0):

The below, assigned to a Text property, gives date in format `yyyyMMdd`:

```
@(Pega-RULES:DateTime).getCurrentDateStamp()
```

Adjusting solution given [here](https://collaborate.pega.com/question/get-current-date-time-expression) as below, would give the desired format `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
@FormatDateTime(@CurrentDateTime(),"yyyy-MM-dd","America/NewYork","en_US")
```

Tested on Pega Personal Edition 8.6.0 using Operator with Default locale "en_US" and Time zone America/New_York.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
@FormatDateTime(@CurrentDateTime(),"MM/dd/yyyy","America/NewYork","en_US")
```